# When specifying a custom key in object, it turns it into an number

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I implement a string based number in a object as the key, when the object is rendered, its returned as a number instead of a string. This is throwing me off because my original array is reordered and then  i want to generate an object based of a number which is an ID within the array row but the issue is, by default, javascript is reordering my object keys by numerical ordered list, instead of the order i tell it to be in.

```
var array = ['1','2','3'].reverse();
var obj = {};
$.each(array, (idx, item) => {
    obj[item.toString()] = item;
});

console.log(array, obj);
```

return is

```
(3) ["3", "2", "1"] {1: "1", 2: "2", 3: "3"}
```

instead of

```
(3) ["3", "2", "1"] {3: "3", 2: "2", 1: "1"}
```

however, this works total fine with non numerical type characters, example below:

```
var array = ['hi','tom','how'].reverse();
var obj = {};
$.each(array, (idx, item) => {
    obj[item.toString()] = item;
});

console.log(array, obj);
```

return as expected

```
(3) ["how", "tom", "hi"] {how: "how", tom: "tom", hi: "hi"}
```

Comment: console.log lies ... try `console.log(Object.keys(obj))` - the keys *should* be in the order created

Comment: @JaromandaX - numeric keys are the exception, they normally appear first and in numeric order, followed by non-numeric keys in the order *they* were created.  (I know they're not really numeric in that all properties have string names, but they're treated as numeric for this purpose.) Anyway, when one needs properties in a certain order one should be using an array, not an object.

Comment: @JaromandaX Object.keys(obj) returns the same...

Comment: Object properties don’t have an order, so you can’t rely on any.

Comment: P.S. Where I said "numeric", I meant "integers >= 0", i.e., numbers that would be valid array indices. Keys like `"1.5"` are treated like non-numeric values for these purposes.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Interesting, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: that's interesting, because I always thought the order in `Object.keys` etc was determined by the order of creation

Comment: @JaromandaX - Well it is. Sort of. If you ignore those pesky non-negative integers. I believe the spec says it should use the same order as a `for..in` loop, but I'm not sure what the spec says about `for..in` order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> by default, javascript is reordering my object keys by numerical ordered list, instead of the order i tell it to be in

Object properties are *not ordered*. There are various ways to get a list of or iterate over properties, but for most of them the order is implementation dependent. However, most current browsers will first iterate over numeric properties in ascending order and then over non-numeric properties in insertion order.

If you want guaranteed order then you should use a `Map` as explained in the other answer, because maps maintain insertion order, or keep using your array to define iteration order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` to store properties in a specific order

```js
var array = ['1','2','3'].reverse();
var obj = new Map;
array.forEach((item, idx) => {
    obj.set(item.toString(), item);
});

console.log([...obj.entries()]);

array.forEach((item, idx) => {
  console.log(obj.get(item))
});

console.log(obj);
```